# MariaDB 111 "Connection refused"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have setup MariaDB.10.0 Galera Cluster (including 3 nodes) on CentOS6.5 and after running for some time, one of the nodes will produce the error below. So far, i have been only able to fix it by re-installing the MariaDb Galera cluster. But this routine has continued for a few days now and would like to solve it once and for all. How can i go about it? By the way, there is a /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file present, so do not even understand why the error comes up in the first place on different nodes on different times.

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111     "Connection refused")'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Comment: Is mysqld running (`ps aux | grep mysqld`) ? Is there any relevant information in the mysql logs (`/var/log/mysql*`) ?

Comment: When this error happens in most cases when i try to restart MariaDB. When it happens, MariaDB stops working because of the error.

Comment: What's the permission + owner  of the mysql.sock ? Maybe mysql can't "restart" the socket because of missing write permission?